# 404 Error Cannot find entry file index.js

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm getting this error:

> The development server returned response 404. Cannot find entry file
>   index.js.

[image]

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vepo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flow-typed": "^2.0.0",
    "generator-rn-toolbox": "^2.2.0",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "native-base": "2.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.3",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    //"react-native-fbsdk": "git://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#065507aa1d2b8b0b6cb50d13117694123f8303fa",
    "react-native-git-upgrade": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.4",
    "react-native-interactable": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-mail": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.16.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-multiple-choice": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.100",
    "react-native-off-canvas-menu": "^0.1.31",
    "react-native-optimized-flatlist": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-redux-router": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "yoga": "^0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "3.0.1",
    "eslint": "^3.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.42.0",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "jest-cli": "^19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, to cause that error?

Comment: did you updated your RN recently?

Comment: your index.js file is in wrong place. you don't need index.android.js and index.ios.js after RN 49. just delete one of them and rename other to index.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an index.js file in root directory of your project and copy your index.android.js or index.ios.js into it.

after RN 49 by default, we don't have different entries for ios and android. so we have just one index.js file that both android and ios use it.

Comment: My current index.ios.js is 

`import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { App } from './src'
//GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest
AppRegistry.registerComponent('vepo', () => App)`


Would this need to be changed at all?

Comment: you don't need these files anymore. rename index.ios.js to index.js and delete index.android.js

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as the solution. I am getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47235645/3935156) when I do that. But it is probably unrelated.

Comment: You can try `rm -rf node_modules` , `npm install`, `react-native link`, `react-native run-andriod`. but be careful. if you linked some libraries manually you need to do that again.